# Sub-optimal result in "Questions that may already have your answer"

Tags: feature-request, search, related-questions

Here is one instance where the "related posts" algorithm's results (while often magic!) weren't great.

A user just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058725/use-jquery-to-create-a-csv-download#20058725):

> Use Jquery to create a CSV Download

Of course, it's a quadruplicate and has a great original [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery) - with 18 upvotes, and a top answer with 56 upvotes:

> Export to csv in jQuery

However, I couldn't really admonish the OP for not looking at the "Questions that may already have your answer" section, because it doesn't show up there. In fact, most suggestions aren't even jQuery related! (The 1st result is the question the OP just created, so that doesn't count.)

[image]

It would be really cool if it could.

Comment: In any heuristic detection system, there will be singular sub-optimal results. The goal is to minimize these to edge cases; the system is designed very well to minimize such cases, but they're still guaranteed to happen. Unless this is a persistent problem with suggestions, I don't think a single case is anything to be concerned about.

Comment: If we placed the tags box first, the chosen tags could be used to possibly improve the results.

Comment: @Emrakul well, how do you minimize edge cases in a heuristic detection system? By pointing them out when they happen, and looking into what causes them. No?

Comment: I just noted (with the help of Nick Craver and Google) that there is an API to save arbitrary files without the data: URL hack.

Comment: @probably I'm not sure a singular case is particularly helpful, though. If you spot a particular pattern in bad results;

Comment: @Emrakul Maybe, maybe not. I'll leave that to the devs to decide. A result where the majority of suggestions were *outside the question's subject matter* may well be worth looking into.

Comment: That is fair. I wouldn't be too concerned with it, though, personally.